# Can't figure out where race condition is occuring

Tags: c++, boost, multithreading, valgrind

I'm using Valgrind --tool=drd to check my application that uses Boost::thread.
Basically, the application populates a  set of "Book" values with "Kehai" values based on inputs through a socket connection.

On a seperate thread, a user can connect and get the books send to them.

Its fairly simple, so i figured using a boost::mutex::scoped_lock on the location that serializes the book and the location that clears out the book data should be suffice to prevent any race conditions. Here is the code:

```
 void Book::clear()
    {
     boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(dataMutex);
     for(int i =NUM_KEHAI-1; i >= 0; --i)
     {
      bid[i].clear();

      ask[i].clear();
     }
    }

    int Book::copyChangedKehaiToString(char* dst) const
    {
     boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(dataMutex);

     sprintf(dst, "%-4s%-13s",market.c_str(),meigara.c_str());
     int loc = 17;
     for(int i = 0; i < Book::NUM_KEHAI; ++i)
     {
      if(ask[i].changed > 0)
      {
       sprintf(dst+loc,"A%i%-21s%-21s%-21s%-8s%-4s",i,ask[i].price.c_str(),ask[i].volume.c_str(),ask[i].number.c_str(),ask[i].postTime.c_str(),ask[i].status.c_str());
       loc += 77;
      }
     }
     for(int i = 0; i < Book::NUM_KEHAI; ++i)
     {
      if(bid[i].changed > 0)
      {
       sprintf(dst+loc,"B%i%-21s%-21s%-21s%-8s%-4s",i,bid[i].price.c_str(),bid[i].volume.c_str(),bid[i].number.c_str(),bid[i].postTime.c_str(),bid[i].status.c_str());
       loc += 77;
      }
     }

     return loc;
    }
```

The clear() function and the copyChangedKehaiToString() function are called in the datagetting thread and data sending thread,respectively.
Also, as a note, the class Book:

```
    struct Book
    {
    private:
     Book(const Book&); Book& operator=(const Book&);
    public:

     static const int NUM_KEHAI=10;
     struct Kehai;
     friend struct Book::Kehai;

     struct Kehai
     {
     private:
       Kehai& operator=(const Kehai&);
     public:
      std::string price;
      std::string volume;
      std::string number;
      std::string postTime;
      std::string status;

      int changed;
      Kehai();
      void copyFrom(const Kehai& other);
      Kehai(const Kehai& other);
      inline void clear()
      {

       price.assign("");
       volume.assign("");
       number.assign("");
       postTime.assign("");
       status.assign("");
       changed = -1;
      }
     };

     std::vector<Kehai> bid;
     std::vector<Kehai> ask;
     tm recTime;
     mutable boost::mutex dataMutex;


     Book();
     void clear();
     int copyChangedKehaiToString(char * dst) const;
      };
```

When using valgrind --tool=drd, i get race condition errors such as the one below:

```
==26330== Conflicting store by thread 1 at 0x0658fbb0 size 4
==26330==    at 0x653AE68: std::string::_M_mutate(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.8)
==26330==    by 0x653AFC9: std::string::_M_replace_safe(unsigned int, unsigned int, char const*, unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.8)
==26330==    by 0x653B064: std::string::assign(char const*, unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.8)
==26330==    by 0x653B134: std::string::assign(char const*) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.8)
==26330==    by 0x8055D64: Book::Kehai::clear() (Book.h:50)
==26330==    by 0x8094A29: Book::clear() (Book.cpp:78)
==26330==    by 0x808537E: RealKernel::start() (RealKernel.cpp:86)
==26330==    by 0x804D15A: main (main.cpp:164)
==26330== Allocation context: BSS section of /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.8
==26330== Other segment start (thread 2)
==26330==    at 0x400BB59: pthread_mutex_unlock (drd_pthread_intercepts.c:633)
==26330==    by 0xC59565: pthread_mutex_unlock (in /lib/libc-2.5.so)
==26330==    by 0x805477C: boost::mutex::unlock() (mutex.hpp:56)
==26330==    by 0x80547C9: boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex>::~unique_lock() (locks.hpp:340)
==26330==    by 0x80949BA: Book::copyChangedKehaiToString(char*) const (Book.cpp:134)
==26330==    by 0x80937EE: BookSerializer::serializeBook(Book const&, std::string const&) (BookSerializer.cpp:41)
==26330==    by 0x8092D05: BookSnapshotManager::getSnaphotDataList() (BookSnapshotManager.cpp:72)
==26330==    by 0x8088179: SnapshotServer::getDataList() (SnapshotServer.cpp:246)
==26330==    by 0x808870F: SnapshotServer::run() (SnapshotServer.cpp:183)
==26330==    by 0x808BAF5: boost::_mfi::mf0<void, RealThread>::operator()(RealThread*) const (mem_fn_template.hpp:49)
==26330==    by 0x808BB4D: void boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<RealThread*> >::operator()<boost::_mfi::mf0<void, RealThread>, boost::_bi::list0>(boost::_bi::type<void>, boost::_mfi::mf0<void, RealThread>&, boost::_bi::list0&, int) (bind.hpp:253)
==26330==    by 0x808BB90: boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf0<void, RealThread>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<RealThread*> > >::operator()() (bind_template.hpp:20)
==26330== Other segment end (thread 2)
==26330==    at 0x400B62A: pthread_mutex_lock (drd_pthread_intercepts.c:580)
==26330==    by 0xC59535: pthread_mutex_lock (in /lib/libc-2.5.so)
==26330==    by 0x80546B8: boost::mutex::lock() (mutex.hpp:51)
==26330==    by 0x805473B: boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex>::lock() (locks.hpp:349)
==26330==    by 0x8054769: boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex>::unique_lock(boost::mutex&) (locks.hpp:227)
==26330==    by 0x8094711: Book::copyChangedKehaiToString(char*) const (Book.cpp:113)
==26330==    by 0x80937EE: BookSerializer::serializeBook(Book const&, std::string const&) (BookSerializer.cpp:41)
==26330==    by 0x808870F: SnapshotServer::run() (SnapshotServer.cpp:183)
==26330==    by 0x808BAF5: boost::_mfi::mf0<void, RealThread>::operator()(RealThread*) const (mem_fn_template.hpp:49)
==26330==    by 0x808BB4D: void boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<RealThread*> >::operator()<boost::_mfi::mf0<void, RealThread>, boost::_bi::list0>(boost::_bi::type<void>, boost::_mfi::mf0<void, RealThread>&, boost::_bi::list0&, int) (bind.hpp:253)
```

For the life of me, i can't figure out where the race condition is. As far as I can tell, clearing the kehai is done only after having taken the mutex, and the same holds true with copying it to a string.
Does anyone have any ideas what could be causing this, or where I should look?

Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After your post I took time to learn about Valgrind and how its output should be read.

I can see the following:

You invoke `Book::clear` which in turns calls `Book::Kehai::clear`, where you assign a value to a string. Inside the `std::string::assign` the STL does something which stores some value at the address 0x0658fbb0.

Meanwhile the other thread has accessed the same memory location, hence this situation is considered a race condition.

Now look at the "context" of the other thread. Valgrind doesn't show its exact stack location, however it shows between which "segments" it has occured. According to Valgrind a segment is a consecutive block of memory accesses bounded by synchronization operations.

We see that this block **starts** with `pthread_mutex_unlock` and **ends** at `pthread_mutex_lock`.
Means - the same memory location was accessed when your mutex was not locked, and that thread was somewhere outside of your two functions.

Now, look at the conflicting memory location information:

```
Allocation context: BSS section of /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.8
```

The BSS means that it's a global/static variable. And it's defined somewhere inside the libstdc.

Conclusion:

This race condition has nothing to do with your data structures. It's related to STL. One thread performs something to an `std::string` (assigns it to an empty string to be exact), whereas the other thread probably does something STL-related as well.

BTW I remember several years ago I've written a multi-threaded application, and there were problems with `std::string` there. As I found out - the STL implementation (which was a Dunkimware) actually implemented string as reference-counted, whereas the reference counting was **not** thread-safe.

Maybe this is what happens to you as well?
Perhaps you should set some compiler flag/option when building a multi-threaded application?

Comment: valdo, thanks for the update. Yeah, i think its the same exact problem. when I switched everything to C-style strings, the errors went away.

Comment: It's a useful post nevertheless. Now I think to test my apps with Valgrind, I use multi-threading heavily.

About strings:
You say the problem disappears when you switch to "C-style strings". But what you call the "C-style strings"? More precisely - what is your policy about their manipulation and lifetime.

I believe the problem is related to the fact if your strings are reference-counted or not. Means - when you assign one string to another: do you actually create a copy of your string, or you allocate another one identical to that?
And if it's reference-counted - is it thread-safe?

Comment: STL is supposed to be thread-safe in the sense that it is not a problem to use them with thread if you lock correctly or if you just perform multi-thread reads

Answer (score 2):

This report may be ignored safely. It is triggered by how std::string is implemented in libstdc++. This issue has been solved in the libstdc++ version included with gcc 4.4.4 or later. See also [GCC bugzilla item #40518](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=40518) for the details.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I'm an idiot and managed to forget that C++ strings are mutable.
I changed the code to use c-style strings and my race condition issues went away.

On an aside for anyone reading this post, does anyone know a good immutable string library for C++? I thought boost had one, but i haven't been able to find anything conclusive on it.

Thanks.

Comment: I've worked with threads and std::strings (or STL containres..) without any problem if everything is correctly protected. What compiler/STL do you use?

Comment: its a known issue with C++ stl strings. Since they use reference counting and are mutable this issue seems to come up quite regularly.

using gcc 4.1 on Centos 5

Comment: as per my comment on another response, you could force the STL to copy rather than clone [string2 = string1.c_str()]. you could even create a "thread-safe string holder" class that encapsulates this work-around and is used in all shared objects that store strings -- then it's harder to forget to do it right, and easier to change implementation if you switch to a non-borked STL.

Answer (score 0):

> STL is supposed to be thread-safe in the sense that it is not a problem to use them with thread if you lock correctly or if you just perform multi-thread reads

Surpirse! Yes, it's *supposed*, but let me tell you a store about what actually *happened*.

I had a multit-hreaded application. There was a datastructure with strings (`std::string`). It was locked with a critical section.

Other objects eventually needed to take strings from there. They made a copy of those strings in the following manner:

```
// Take a string
std::string str;
{
    Autolock l(g_CritSect);
    str = g_SomeStr;
}
```

The same strategy was used to adjust those strings:

```
// Put a string
std::string str;
{
    Autolock l(g_CritSect);
    g_SomeStr = str;
}
```

And, guess what? Crashes!

But why? Because the string's assignment statement doesn't really produce a copy of the memory block holding the string. Instead the same memory block is reused (referenced).

Well, this is not necessarily bad. But the bad thing was that std::string implemented reference counting of the strings not in a thread-safe way. It used regular arithmetic ++ and -- instead of `InterlockedIncrement` and etc.

What happened is that the `str` object references the same string. And then it eventually dereferences it in its destructor (or when explicitly assigned to another string). And this happens **outside** of the locked region.

So that those strings may not be used in a multi-threaded application. And it's almost impossible to implement correct locking to work this around, because the actual referenced data passes silently from object to object.

And **that** implementation of STL was declared thread-safe.

Comment: Presumably you could force the copy to actually copy, e.g. g_SomeStr = str.c_str() ? [Obviously a horrible work-around, and better to switch to a non-borked STL.]

Comment: Yes there are always bad implementation, but it's not always the case